# In flex 3, need to make part of checkbox label to be bold

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

In flex 3, How to make part of checkbox label to be in bold font?
say checkbox label is " remember values on the datagrid". Need to make the text "datagrid" alone bolded. Can anyone please help on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the perfect solution, but it will get you started. If you extend the CheckBox class, you can override the `updateDisplayList()` method, and set the label of the checkbox using it's `htmlText` property.

Then use this custom checkbox and pass in a label with HTML.

The problems with this solution:

- the super class is not measuring the HTML formatted text (you could implement the `measure()` Flex life cycle method)
- after super.updateDisplayList() does all of it's work, we then sort of undo it by using the  `htmlText` property

HTMLTextCheckBox.as:

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.CheckBox;

    public class HtmlTextCheckBox extends CheckBox
    {
        public function HtmlTextCheckBox()
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            textField.htmlText = label;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it MXML:

```
<local:HtmlTextCheckBox label="this is the &lt;b&gt;bold part&lt;/b&gt;"/>
```

Or in AS3:

```
var cb:HtmlTextCheckBox = new HtmlTextCheckBox();
cb.text = "this is the <b>bold part</b>";
```